# nodewebkit failing install in node 0.8

Tags: node.js, npm, node-webkit

I'm trying to install nodewebkit in node version 0.8.

```
> nvm use 0.8
> npm update
> npm install -g nodewebkit

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/nodewebkit
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/nodewebkit
npm WARN engine nodewebkit@0.8.6: wanted: {"node":">= 0.10.0"} (current: {"node":"v0.8.26","npm":"1.2.30"})
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/download
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/multimeter
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/yargs
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf
npm ERR! Error: No compatible version found: rimraf@'^2.2.2'
npm ERR! Valid install targets:
npm ERR! ["1.0.0","1.0.1","1.0.2","1.0.4","1.0.5","1.0.6","1.0.7","1.0.8","1.0.9","2.0.0","2.0.1","2.0.2","2.0.3","2.1.0","2.1.1","2.1.2","2.1.3","2.1.4","2.2.0","2.2.1","2.2.2","2.2.3","2.2.4","2.2.5","2.2.6"]
npm ERR!    at installTargetsError (/home/charleswall/.nvm/v0.8.26/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:719:10)
npm ERR!    at /home/charleswall/.nvm/v0.8.26/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:641:10
npm ERR!    at saved (/home/charleswall/.nvm/v0.8.26/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/get.js:138:7)
npm ERR!    at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:297:15)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!    <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!    <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.8.0-29-generic
npm ERR! command "/home/charleswall/.nvm/v0.8.26/bin/node" "/home/charleswall/.nvm/v0.8.26/bin/npm" "install" "nodewebkit"
npm ERR! cwd /home/charleswall/projects/liveos-vnc-proxy
npm ERR! node -v v0.8.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.30
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/download
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/yargs
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/multimeter
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!    /home/charleswall/projects/liveos-vnc-proxy/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Strangely, this works in node 0.10. I'm on ubuntu 12.04. I tried installing rimraf (whatever that is) separately to no avail. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

[rimraf](https://www.npmjs.org/package/rimraf) is a deep deletion module for node (like `rm -rf`)

What npm states is that it cannot install version 2.2.2 of rimraf as it's probably installing a more recent one (2.2.6 seems from your log).
To force npm to install the right version run this command:

```
npm install rimraf@2.2.2 -g
```

Comment: Unfortunately there was an entire group of modules that were failing to install rimraf just happened to be the one failing when I was installing. I've since switched to node 0.10. Thanks for your help though.